# How to read a password protected xlsx file into R?

Tags: r, excel

I tried with XLConnect but it doesn't work.

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("file.xlsx")
```

This is the error:

> Error: EncryptedDocumentException (Java): The supplied spreadsheet seems to be an Encrypted .xlsx file. It must be decrypted before use by XSSF, it cannot be used by HSSF
>   **wb <- loadWorkbook("File.xlsx",password="xxxxx")**
>
> Error: NoSuchMethodError (Java): org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook;

Comment: Is the package xlsx also loaded?

Packages XLConnect and xlsx are not compatible and can not be loaded at the same time. Reason is that XLConnect (with XLConnectJars) and xlsx with (xlsxjars) ship with different versions of Apache POI. Depending on which package is loaded first, the other package won't work. [src](https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/issues/73)

Comment: @RobertoMoratore the package xlsx isn't loaded !!@KenWhite I don't know how to decrypt a file using XSSF.

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2018/05/06/remove-password-protection-from-excel-sheets-using-r/) (from *"R" you ready?*) explains how to remove password protection from Excel sheets using R. Note: The approach only works for .xlsx files, which is what you wanted anyway.